# Google Chrome dialog boxes not autofilling with LastPass or Chrome Password Manager

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, lastpass

## Problem with Google Chrome dialog boxes not auto-filling

When I try to login to my (Netgear) router at `192.168.1.1` a dialog box appears and asks me to input username and password:
[image: chrome login dialog box]

(Plus it says the connection to the website is not secure)

After login I saved the credentials in LastPass and in the Google Chrome password manager. But when I log out and open the page again there is nothing autofilled or asking me if I want to autofill the credentials. Just the blank dialog box again.

--> Autofill / autologin is enabled both in LastPass and in Chrome.

But when I hover over the vault entry and click on `open page` directly in the LastPass extension, it works fine and I am automatically logged in without the dialog box appearing!

Does anyone know how to let login dialogs like this be auto-filled or even have autologin?

### More Info:

- **OS**: `Windows 10 Home Version 2004`
- **Chrome version**: `86.0.4240.198`
- I am using the LastPass Chrome extension
- It's not only this page and this computer where I have this problem but with every dialog box like this (I only tried Windows 10 with Google Chrome though).